# Where do I call the Subclass? (reselectable UISegmentControl Swift 3)

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a subclass for a UISegmentedControl which is called `SegControl` in a Cocoa Touch Class.

```
class SegControl: UISegmentedControl {
override var = "test"
}
```

And now I have a UISegmentControl in my ViewController what do I have to do that this conforms to my custom class?

EDIT:
Full code for a Reselectable UISegmentControl for Swift 3

```
class ReselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    @IBInspectable var allowReselection: Bool = true
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if allowReselection && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
                if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

UISegmentControl:

```
var savedSegment: Int = -1

    @IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: ReselectableSegmentedControl) {

        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == savedSegment) {
            sender.selectedSegmentIndex =  UISegmentedControlNoSegment
            savedSegment = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
        }
        else {
            savedSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        }
```

Comment: Well, you simply declare it as a `SegControl` rather than a `UISegmentedControl`. If you are using it in IB, then you can change the class of the control in IB, too...

Comment: I just change it like this: @IBAction func segment(_  sender: SegControl) ?

Comment: Well, if that's the action it triggers, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear but to start you need to replace any references to `UISegmentedControl` with `SegControl`. This includes updating any references in code as well as changing the class name of the object in any storyboard or xib.

You are also going to need to add the proper `init` methods to your subclass so you can create instances of it.

And of course you need to added whatever additional code that makes having this subclass useful.

Comment: Oh wow I forgot to change it in the Storyboard. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

add a default UISegmentControl in your layout builder

then click on it and in the side menu under identity inspector -> class 
write your class name SegControl

[image]